# SharedPreferences not saving when using notification intent

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-notifications

I have the following code in my activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String databaseVersionKey = "databaseVersion";
    int databaseVersion = MyStore.DATABASE_VERSION;

    // check if the database needs to be upgraded
    if (MyStore.DATABASE_VERSION != sharedPreferences.getInt(databaseVersionKey, 0)) {
        Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
        e.putInt(databaseVersionKey, databaseVersion);
        boolean result = e.commit(); // result is true

        ...
    }

...
```

}

I debug in and the first time my activity is called the database version is checked, and then set if not current.

However when my activity gets called from my notification intent, the value in shared preferences is not set.  I.E. once I launch my app, I click home button, then slide notification bar down and click my notification which fires the above activity again.  I notice when I debug in again that my dataVersion did not seem to get set.

Here is the code I use to create the notification intent that launches the same activity as above:

```
    private void createNotification() {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My App")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle("My App");

        String msg = "You are logged in, click to open app.";
        bigTextStyle.bigText(msg);
        builder.setContentText(msg);

        builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
    }
```

I have tried commit and apply without any luck in either.  The first time that MyActivity is launched from the notification intent the value of databaseVersion does not appear to be set.  This is after I watched it get successful set on app launch.

This one is driving me nuts, any ideas???

EDIT for @alfasin

getDefaultSharedPreferences android source code:

```
public static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context),
        getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());
}

private static String getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName() + "_preferences";
}

private static int getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode() {
    return Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
}
```

My package name does not change from call to call, hence I will get the same SharedPreferences each time.

Comment: Isn't this just a lifecycle problem? An activity is not necessarily recreated when you launch it again. Also, it seems that you have not shared the code for changing the version number, but I assume that you do...